# ListView unrelated model lookup

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm looking for a way to bring data from one model into a view of another model for a ListView.  Basically, when the user opens up the listview of the vocabulary model, I need to look up and pull out the associated pinyin field from the dictionary model by using the vocab field.  There is some example code at the bottom of the codeview that would be how I would match up a `Vocabulary.vocab` with a `Dictionary.pinyin`.

```
############### Models
​
class Vocabulary(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vocab = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    translation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=LEVELS, default=0)
    audio = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = RandomManager()
​
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['created_by', 'vocab'], name='User Vocab Duplicate Check')
        ]
        verbose_name = "Chinese Vocabulary"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
​
    # this function will be invoked when this model object is foreign key of other model(for example Employee model.).
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vocab
​
class Dictionary(models.Model):
    traditional = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    simplified = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pinyin = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    simplified_radical = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hsk_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=LEVELS, default=0)
    frequency_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    phrase_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    radical_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    definition = models.TextField()
    objects = RandomManager()
​
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Dictionary"
        verbose_name_plural = "Dictionary"
​
    def __str__(self):
        return self.simplified
​
################# Views
​
class VocabDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Vocabulary
    template_name = 'library/vocab_details.html'
​
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['dictionary'] = Dictionary.objects.get(simplified=self.object.vocab)
        return context
​
​
class VocabListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Vocabulary
    template_name = 'library/vocab_list.html'
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Vocabulary.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
​
    '''
    hao = Vocabulary.objects.get(vocab='你')
    haodict = Dictionary.objects.get(simplified=hao.vocab)
    haopin = hao_dict.pinyin
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you objects were related, you could override the `get_queryset` to use `select_related` or similar in order to get the related objects. But it doesn't look like you can do that because the objects aren't related.

So you could either not use a `ListView` and gather your objects in the context, or override the context to get the `Dictionary` objects you want. Sounds like you'd do something like;

```
def get_context_data(**kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    dicts = Dictionary.objects.filter(pinyin__in=self.object_list.values_list('vocab', flat=True))
    context['dictionaries'] = dicts
    return context
```